# How to determine courant number in a multiphase simulation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

How to determine the Courant number in multiphase flow simulation?

I tried to simulate a fluid flow with two phases but it went divergent. How to make the simulation stable? I've read the courant number and applying various time step, mesh size, and velocity boundary condition but it didn't give me any progress.

Does the volume fraction BC also affect the courant number? Is there any calculation or formula or criterion to make a multiphase simulation stable? Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of multiphase flow are you considering? Is it purely an advection PDE? Or is there diffusion terms involved? What kind of CFL condition are you trying to use currently?

Comment: @KyleKanos it is a purely advection PDE with no diffusion terms. I suppose the Courant number is between 0.2-0.8

Answer (score 1):

In principle, CFL is not affected by the presence of a second fluid.

To put it very naively, the CFL number is an estimate of how many cells ($\Delta x$) a fluid particle travels within a timestep $\Delta t$ in a given velocity field $U$,  $$CFL=\frac{U\Delta t}{\Delta x}.$$

Now if the particle is fluid A or fluid B does not make any difference.

When you simulate flows that are strongly influenced by capillary forces, you should also keep in mind another timestep constraint, namely the capillary timestep constraint

$$\Delta t_{\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{\rho_A+\rho_B}{2\pi\sigma}\Delta x^3}.$$

This timestep restriction is associated with the propagation of the capillary waves on the interface between the two fluids A and B. You can read more here (https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.01963).

In general, the second constraint is more restrictive than the first one because of the $\Delta x^{3/2}$ term.

CFL is related to your internal field and not your boundaries.

Depending on the VOF method you use there is a certain behaviour if you use an algebraic method probably it can "survive" higher CFL numbers CFL>1 in contrast to that geometric VOF usually work fine for CFL<1.

Best
K